# How do I show the pointer after touch interaction in Windows 8

Tags: touch, accessibility, windows-8

When you touch the screen in Windows 8, the mouse pointer  is hidden until you move the mouse (or other pointing device).  This happens in both desktop and Metro interfaces.

We have a program that allows people to move the mouse pointer using other input methods (such as a joystick), so I need to ensure the mouse pointer is visible.

How can I force the mouse pointer to be displayed?

Comment: Can't you display your own pointer for that? What stack are you using? XAML, HTML or C++?

Comment: This is a COM program that runs on the desktop for accessibility.
We could display a custom pointer on top of the "real" one, but it wouldn't necessarily be the right shape or respect the user's pointer settings in Windows (which are often changed for accessibility) so it would be better if we could re-show the Windows pointer.

Answer (score 1):

you can set the flag of touch feedback.

`[setting]`  `->[control panel]->[pen and touch]->[touch feekback]` item,there is a checkbox that is `[show visual feedback when touch the screen]`.If you cann't select the checkbox, you can show the mouse pointer without coding anything when touching the screen.

Comment: This does not show the pointer, it just shows when you touch the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject mouse movement before you start joystick control, using Windows API:

```
POINT p;
GetCursorPos(&p);

MOUSEINPUT mi;
mi.dx = (LONG) ((p.x * 65535) / screen_width);
mi.dy = (LONG) ((p.y * 65535) / screen_height);
mi.mouseData = 0;
mi.dwFlags = type | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE;
mi.time = 0;
mi.dwExtraInfo = NULL;

INPUT input;
input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
input.mi   = mi;

SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
```